# Reset database between tests when using Testcontainers and Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, testcontainers

If I am using a singleton database container in my integration tests, how can I make sure the database is in a clean state (no data) before each test? The codebase is using Liquibase for data migrations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to delete all rows inside your database after/before each test, you can:

1. Use `@Transactional` for your tests and Spring will rollback the transaction after each test
2. Use the `JdbcTemplate`/`YourEntityRepository` (Spring Data JPA Repositories) and delete them with a `DELETE` SQL query (`JdbcTemplate`) or `.deleteAll()` (Spring Data JPA repositories) as part of JUnit Jupiters `@BeforeEach`/`@AfterEach`

Your applied DDL scripts (`CREATE`) from Liquibase will remain and each test starts with a valid schema.

Comment: I went with option 2 since Hibernate (which is the JPA implementation we're using) will clean up the tables correctly in case some tables have relations.

Comment: Option 1) definitely does *not* work for me.

Comment: Option 1 worked for me. It is like the database has been refreshed. At least in my early tests. Two tests on the same test class inserts rows. In the second test, the row inserted on the first one was not on the database.

Comment: Be careful with option 1. It could leat to false negative test results.

Answer (score 0):

In my Kotlin tests, I found the simplest way to clear out my DB tables between tests inside a single `@SpringBootTest` class was to add something like:

```
@Sql(statements=["DELETE FROM xxx", "DELETE FROM yyy"])
```

to my test class. This simply wipes the data from the xxx and yyy tables, so you will want to add your SQL DDL statements the right order to avoid constraint violations, etc.

You can also add the @Sql statement to specific @Test methods that require a clean DB, instead of adding it at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pre-Liquibase](https://github.com/lbruun/Pre-Liquibase) for this purpose. It works for tests too.

The idea is that each test class runs in its own schema (or even its own catalog, depending on database platform) and that this is created on-the-fly. This has the added benefit that your test classes can run in parallel even if the same database is shared for all of your CI pipeline.

1. Add the Pre-Liquibase dependency to your project. If you only use Pre-Liquibase for testing then add it using scope, like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lbruun.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>preliquibase-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>  ---latest-version---  </version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

2. Add SQL file(s) to folder `src/test/resources/preliquibase/`, for example file `postgresql.sql`:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${spring.liquibase.default-schema};
```

3. Annotate your Spring Boot tests with `@TestPropertySource` so that you override the value for database schema name, like so:

```java
// We want the database provided by the CI environment, so we don't want
// Spring Boot to attempt to start one. Hence we disable such feature.
// The definition of the CI datasource likely sits in a profile specific
// properties file, such as src/test/resources/application-jenkins.properties
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE) // deactivate the default behaviour, YMMV
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=test_schema_e8b9ef9a",
    "spring.liquibase.default-schema=test_schema_e8b9ef9a"
    })
public class PersistenceTest {
    ...
}
```

The tests for `PersistenceTest` will now execute in its own database schema, `test_schema_e8b9ef9a`. You get the idea.

The above is pretty lean. It uses Spring Boot test slicing (the `@DataJpaTest` annotation) so it starts quickly.